# How to send data using ajax in cakephp3?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I working cakephp3. I have two dropdown select. The first menu list values is displayed with the loading page and then The second menu list values will be filled with the user's choice from the first menu. I do this with ajax but I don't how to send/get data to/from ajax.

In view (addroom.ctp) :

```
<form method="post" action="#" name="setRoom">
                    <?php
                    echo '<select name = "dorm" id="dorm" >';
                    foreach ($row as $a) {

                        echo '<option>' . "$a" . '</option>';
                    }
                    echo '</select>';

                    ?>

</form>
```

In ajax.js in webroot:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dorm').change(function () {
            var dorm = $('#dorm').val();
            if (dorm == '') {
                $('#roomm').html("choose dormitory!");
            }
            $.ajax({
            url: "addroom.ctp",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: dorm,
                    success: function (data) {
                            alert("ok");
                    }
        });
    });

}
```

In Controller:

```
 class UesrmoreinfoesController extends AppController {

  public function addroom() {
    $gender = $this->request->Session()->read('Auth.User.gender');
    $url = $this->params['url'];
    $dorm = $url['dorm'];
    $this->typeDormitory($gender);
    $this->numberRooms($dorm);
  }

 }
```

The function `typeDormitory($gender)` returns `$row` in the first menu list and `numberRooms($dorm)` returns `$rooms` in the second menu list.

The first menu data are displayed correctly.
How to get value from the first dropdown and post for ajax?

Comment: You might want to look into the chained dropdowns @ http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples :) The code is open source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create form with [form helper](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html)
2. Change `url: "addroom.ctp"` to `url: $("form").attr("action");`